# How to run executable file after TFS Build

Tags: deployment, batch-file, workflow-activity, build-agent

My task is:

after TFS build

1) On a server X stop file Example.exe

2) Copy files from Drop Location into server X

3) Run a brand-new version of Example.exe on a server X

I'm updating DefaultTemplate.xaml in TFS 2012, Visual Studio 2012.
I'm entering InvokeProcess activity that runs Do.bat script.

My Build Agent copies files to server X and then runs file \X...\Do.bat

Do.bat is something like

```
taskkill /F /IM Example.exe
start \\%~p0Example.exe
```

So, the problem is the Example.exe is running on a Build Agent, not on server X.

How can I make build agent run an executable file on another server?
The additional question - is it worth using bat files as scripts in TFS Build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`PsExec`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) is a SysInternals tool that will run a process on a remote computer.

PowerShell is also able to [launch a process remotely.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819505.aspx)

As to your additional question, I have generally found it more worthwhile customizing my tfs builds writing build activities in C# and/or using the built-in activities and customizing the build template in xaml.  Not fun, but I find external scripts run into more permissions issues and are difficult to debug.  I've tried them, and then I usually end up back in C#.

Comment: The "launch a process remotely" link is now at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-7